# Putty restart session and show previous visible data and path

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, putty

I am running a task on my Ubuntu 18.04 Server which imports and processes a huge file.

I am running putty over SSH on my laptop to administrate the whole process and the output from the task.

The laptop is not capable to run the whole time of the import and to show the process. I want to make it possible to login at a later time and see the same things I saw at the earlier stage.

Is this possible?

Duplicate Edit: I dont need this for a lag or a disconned over minutes. I want to be able to reconnect after some days and still see the same. I want a similiar functionality like Remote Desktop for Windows.

Comment: Use tmux or the older screen. The linked question _does_ cover your described situation perfectly.

Comment: If you like tricky solutions, you can also make screen to your login shell (or start a `screen -r -d` from .profile) :-)